# InvalidArgumentError: tensorflow logits and labels still not broadcastable

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling, conv-neural-network, taylor-series

I tried to build ResNet like a convolutional model for RGB image classification, I used cifar-10 images dataset for training my model. When I compiled and evaluated the model, I had an invalid argument error said that logits and labels must be broadcastable, I am not sure the source of this error. How can I get rid of this error? can anyone point me out what's wrong with me code? any idea to fix this? thanks

**my current attempt**:

```
    h = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape)(h)
    h = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')(h)
    h = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(h)
    h = Dropout(0.25)(h)
    h = Flatten()(h)
    h = Dense(512, activation='relu')(h)
    h = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(h)
    model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=h)
    return model

my_model = resNet_2(train_imgs)
my_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
model_history = my_model.fit(train_imgs, train_label_one_hot, batch_size=64, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_imgs, test_label_one_hot))
my_model.evaluate(train_imgs, train_label_one_hot)
my_model.evaluate(test_imgs, test_label_one_hot)
```

**error**

> ```
> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-40-5a4cccc5d1ec> in <module>()
>       3 # my_model.summary()
>       4 # ## use cifar-10 image dataset
> ----> 5 my_history = my_model.fit(train_imgs, train_label_one_hot, batch_size=64, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_imgs,
> ```
>
> test_label_one_hot))
>             6 my_model.evaluate(train_imgs, train_label_one_hot)
>             7 my_model.evaluate(test_imgs, test_label_one_hot)
>
> ```
> 8 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py
> ```
>
> in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
>            58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
>            59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
>       ---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
>            61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
>            62     if name is not None:
>
> ```
> InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[192,10] labels_size=[64,10]
>    [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at
> ```
>
> :5) ]]
>   [Op:__inference_train_function_119387]

I don't understand why this error happened, is is problem of my model or incorrect input/output dim setting? any quick shot to trace the error and make model evaluation works fine? any thought? thanks

**update**:

here I used Taylor expansion to build my computational model, using `exp_order` means that I used the Taylor series of 2 expansion terms or approximation order. can anyone why my model gave such an error? any way to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from this part of code

```
def get_exp(x, exp_order):
        x_ = x[..., None] 
        x_ = tf.tile(x_, multiples=[1, 1, exp_order + 1]) 
        pows = tf.range(0, exp_order + 1, dtype=tf.float32)
        x_p = tf.pow(x_, pows)
        return x_p
```

when exp_order = 2, then `tf.tile` is making the size of `x_` to be three multiples. When your input data is of batch_size = 64, the above code is expecting size to be 192. When I input `exp_order = 0`, then it runs the code without any issue. So you need to update that part of the code.Hope it helps.

Comment: Please check the your code that I modified and ran https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Taylor_series.ipynb

Comment: I will take a look at it layer today. Thanks